# How to use ROS in Eclipse when make eclipse-project did not worked?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi I want to run the beginner_tutorials in Eclipse. I have installed Eclipse for c++ and ROS is working fin, but I can not make the eclipse project! I have copied my beginner tutorial from catkin_ws and past it in Eclipse's workspace then when I try to make it (by following this side http://wiki.ros.org/IDEs#Eclipse) I get this message: `~/workspace/beginner_tutorials$ make eclipse-project make: *** No rule to make target` eclipse-project'.  Stop.`

How can I fix this problem ?

---

Edit: thanks @ahendrix and @emersonfs for guidance. But unfortunately I did not have success.
It mention that "Now you can import your project as existing project into workspace" !

1. Should I copy the beginner_tutorials folder from /catkin_ws/build and past it in Eclipse Workspace, open Eclipse and import the beginner_tutorials project ? Or
2. Should I open Eclipse and then import the project from the /catkin_ws/build ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/225567/how-to-use-ros-in-eclipse-when-make-eclipse-project-did-not-worked-?/) by [RosUser](https://answers.ros.org/users/25698/rosuser/) on ROS Answers with karma: 81 on 2016-02-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-02-25**:
@RosUser: please don't post answers unless you actually want to answer a question. For updates / to tell us what you've tried, please use the *edit* button/link. I've already merged your update into your question for you.

As to your new question: it's option 2: import them, *never* copy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As clearly stated on the IDEs page, the `make ecplipse-project` command only works for rosbuild. Start with section 2.2 (catkin) instead.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-02-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0